# No suitable driver found for jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/database

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc

I'm using NetBeans to learn how to use sql in Java. However, I get that error even though I'm doing everything right. Here is my connection statement:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", 
    "root", "MsqJ449?");
```

Also, I added the mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar to my Compile Time and Run Time libraries under Properties in NetBeans. That database exists in MySQL. What else could the problem be?

Comment: what sort of project is this in?

Comment: Looks like the mysql connectivity jar is not available at runtime. Make sure to add this library in the build path. Also, how are you executing/running the application?

Comment: You have a typo in the JDBC url (jbdc != jdbc)

Comment: I just found that typo! Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

You need to load the driver, by calling:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

at some point before you use it.

Comment: You don't need this if you're using JDBC 4 since Java SE 7.

Comment: @LuigiMendoza In fact JDBC 4 dates from 2007 and Java 6.

Answer (score -2):

The jdbc driver need to be load to your JVM by Class.forName(drivername) method, try to call this method before you get connection.

Comment: Or you can indicate this using the jdbc.drivers system property at runtime

Comment: That is not necessary with JDBC 4 compliant drivers (JDBC 4 was introduced in Java 6)